# How to concatenate form array inputs before submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Example code:

```
<form method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='one'> <!-- checked -->
<input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='two'>
<input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='three'> <!-- checked -->

<input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo[]" value='Forty'>
<input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo[]" value='Fifty'> <!-- checked -->
</form>
```

On form submission the URL should look like:

`http://some-website.tld/action?anythingOne=one,three&otherThingTwo=Fifty`

What I am observing now is,

`http://some-website.tld/action?anythingOne=one&anythingOne=three&otherThingTwo=Fifty`

The `serialize()` or `serializeArray()` is not working in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: The result that you are observing now is valid. It will be correctly parsed on server-side as an array of strings. Why do you want to use specific format?

Comment: The URL may be shared in social sites and or among the visitors. So the expectation format may look more meaningful than the actual one.

Comment: If i remember right using array's on `name's` is only useful when using `PHP`. With `JS` you can do better than that. I would just select all the input-fields `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` and then filter and loop them by each unique name separately. See about filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I have a feeling you should be handling the arrays server side rather than modifying with your query string. is this submitting to a php script or something else? if you really want a comma separated list of values in the end it would be easy enough to do something like `implode(',',$_GET['anythingOne'])` if it's php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create query string in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230732/how-to-create-query-string-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all the checked boxer and `join` the different parts of the strings.This may not be the most neat or efficient solution, but it works. I used a button to trigger the concatenation. See my comments within the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  /* concatenate anythingOne form*/
  //collect anythingOne input
  var joined_serialized = []
  var anythingOne = [];
  $.each($("input[name='anythingOne[]']:checked"), function(){            
   anythingOne.push($(this).val());
  });
  //join otherThingTwo input
  var anythingOne_serialized = "";
  if(anythingOne.length > 0){ //only collect if checked
   anythingOne_serialized =  "anythingOne=" + anythingOne.join(",");
   joined_serialized.push(anythingOne_serialized)
  }
  
  /* concatenate otherThingTwo form*/
  //collect otherThingTwo input
  var otherThingTwo = []
  $.each($("input[name='otherThingTwo[]']:checked"), function(){            
   otherThingTwo.push($(this).val());
  });
  //join otherThingTwo input
  var otherThingTwo_serialized = "";
  if(otherThingTwo.length > 0){ //only collect if checked
   otherThingTwo_serialized =  "otherThingTwo=" + otherThingTwo.join(",");
   joined_serialized.push(otherThingTwo_serialized)
  }
  
  /*join different form names*/
  var joined_serialized = joined_serialized.join("&")
  
  if(joined_serialized.length == 1){ //remove last & if only one form is checked
   joined_serialized = joined_serialized.slice(0, -1)
  }
  
  /*concatenated forms with website*/
  var result = "http://some-website.tld/action?"+joined_serialized
  console.log(result) //E.g. when Two, Three and Forty are checked: http://some-website.tld/action?anythingOne=two,three&otherThingTwo=Forty 
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='one'> <!-- checked -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='two'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='three'> <!-- checked -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo[]" value='Forty'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo[]" value='Fifty'> <!-- checked -->      
</form>
<button>submit<button/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the result of `.serializeArray` and transform it into the desired format:

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    
    var dataByKey = data
      .reduce((result, entry) => {
        var name = entry.name.replace(/\[\]$/, '');
        (result[name] || (result[name] = [])).push(entry.value);
        return result;
      }, {});
      
    Object.keys(dataByKey)
      .forEach((key, _) => dataByKey[key] = dataByKey[key].join(','));
    
    console.log(dataByKey);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='one'>1
    <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='two'>2
    <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='three'>3
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo[]" value='Forty'>40
    <input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo[]" value='Fifty'>50
  </fieldset>
  
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can also use pure javascript without jQuery to get all the checked checkboxes' value, http://jsfiddle.net/jx76dpkh/1/

```
<form id="myForm" method="get">
         <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='one'>1
         <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='two'>2
         <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne[]" value='three'>3
         <input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo[]" value='Forty'>40
         <input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo[]" value='Fifty'>50
         <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     let checkboxes = Array.from(myForm.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');// build the array like element list to an array
     let anythingOne = checkboxes.filter( box => box.name === 'anythingOne[]').map(item => item.value);
     let otherThingTwo = checkboxes.filter( box => box.name === 'otherThingTwo[]').map(item => item.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get query string parameters using by [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method. Then use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group parameter values by name, and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get array of key-value pairs. Then it is possible to concatenate the pairs separated by `&` using [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method. For example the following snippet creates a target URL using actual value of the form [action](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) (current URL by default) and values of checked checkboxes:

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  var queryString = $(this).serializeArray()
    .reduce(function(transformed, current) {
      var existing = transformed.find(function(param) {
        return param.name === current.name;
      });
      if (existing)
        existing.value += (',' + current.value);
      else
        transformed.push(current);
      return transformed;
    }, [])
    .map(function(param) {
      return param.name + '=' + param.value;
    })
    .join('&');
  var action = $(this).prop('action');
  var delimiter = (~action.indexOf('?')) ? '&' : '?';
  $(this).prop('action', action + delimiter + queryString);
  
  // Only for display result. Remove on real page.
  var url = $(this).prop('action');
  console.log(url);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="GET">
  <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne" value='one'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne" value='two'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="anythingOne" value='three'>

  <input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo" value='Forty'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="otherThingTwo" value='Fifty'>

  <button type="submit">Show target URL</button>
</form>
```

The latest 3 lines are used only to prevent the form sending and display resulted URL.

Also it is possible to solve the question using only [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) mathod and regular expressions, but it requires lookbehind assertion support in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In case, you are allowed to change html, here is a solution using hidden fields.

```js
function updateChecks() {

  $.each(['anythingOne', 'otherThingTwo'], function(i, field) {
    var values = $('input[type=checkbox][data-for=' + field + ']:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(',');
    $('input[type=hidden][name=' + field + ']').val(values);

  });
}
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    updateChecks();
  });
  updateChecks();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="anythingOne" value='' />
  <input type="hidden" name="otherThingTwo" value='' />
  <input type="checkbox" data-for="anythingOne" value='one' checked='' />
  <input type="checkbox" data-for="anythingOne" value='two' />
  <input type="checkbox" data-for="anythingOne" value='three' checked='' />
  <input type="checkbox" data-for="otherThingTwo" value='Forty' />
  <input type="checkbox" data-for="otherThingTwo" value='Fifty' checked='' />
</form>
```